# .fadeOut and .fadeIn not working in IE

Tags: jquery, opencart

I'm currently having a problem with a paid extension I've installed in Open Cart, what its meant to do is instead of showing the difference in price for an option, preceded by a + next to the original base option price, it adds the two together.

For example the original Open Cart without the module will show where the price is displayed:

Base product selected
 Price displayed: "£10.00"

Optional extra selected:
 Price displayed: "£10.00 + £1.50"

With Extension it would add the £1.50 to the price and display "£11.50".

Everything works fine in FireFox and chrome, but in IE8 (and the site has to work in IE8 and above) there is a line of code in the extension that doesn't seem to work.

The code below makes the old price fade out when an optional extra is selected, and makes the new price fade in, IE8 reports errors on these lines and when an optional extra is selected the price just vanishes, no fade out, no fade in, and doesn't return even if the original product without the optional extra is selected.

Here's the problematic code:

```
jQuery('#opu_price').fadeOut('100').queue(function(n){jQuery(this).html(mydata.price); n();}).fadeIn('100');
jQuery('#opu_special').fadeOut('100').delay(100).queue(function(n){jQuery(this).html(mydata.special); n();}).fadeIn('100');
jQuery('#opu_tax').fadeOut('100').delay(200).queue(function(n){jQuery(this).html(mydata.tax); n();}).fadeIn('100');
```

What I would like if you would please help me, is to remove the fade in effect and just have the price display instantly, its not a big deal if there is no fade effects, but I'm inexperienced in jQuery and JavaScript and don't really know how to modify the code.

**EDIT:**

Here are the IE8 error messages as requested

Webpage error details

```
Message: Object doesn't support this property or method Line: 485 Char: 4 Code: 0 URI: http://www.cfmachinery.co.uk/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=383
Message: Object expected Line: 484 Char: 81 Code: 0 URI: http://www.cfmachinery.co.uk/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=383
```

You wont be able to access the website because it isn't live yet so here are lines 484 and 485 respectivley:

```
$('#opu_price').fadeOut('100').queue(function(n){$(this).html(mydata.price); n();}).fadeIn('100');
$('#opu_special').fadeOut('100').delay(100).queue(function(n){$(this).html(mydata.special); n();}).fadeIn('100');
```

Comment: `IE8 reports errors on these lines`, please post those errors as that could be important information.

Comment: I believe I could try adding "(this).hide()" to the code so that it just vanishes and re- appears in IE8, but am not sure where to make these additions, I'll experiment with it. Please anyone who can help, I'd be very, very grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you show more of your OpenCart page code please. Try adding `charset` inside the `script` tags too.

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="//some-cdn.com/j.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $('#opu_price').fadeOut('100').queue(function (n) {
        $(this).html(mydata.price);
        n();
    }).fadeIn('100');
    $('#opu_special').fadeOut('100').delay(100).queue(function (n) {
        $(this).html(mydata.special);
        n();
    }).fadeIn('100');
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I appreciate it. Turns out it was nothing to do with the actual code, I was just using an old jQuery library once I changed it to a newer one the fade didn't work in IE but it just hid the old value and displayed the new one.Took me a while to realize because I could have sworn I updated the library when it first started mis-behaving.